# which code is better when we use c++ std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Here is the code.

1.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>> ab_map;
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, double>& item = ab_map[std::to_string(i)];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        item.emplace(std::to_string(j), 10.0);
    }
}
```

2. 

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<std::string, double>> ab_map;
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, double> item;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        item.emplace(std::to_string(j), 10.0);
    }
    ab_map.emplace(std::to_string(i), std::move(item));
}
```

I think the second usage is better. But after executing the code and calculating the cost time. I found that the first one is better.  Why?

test1:
first: 183947 microseconds;
second: 186965 microseconds

test2:
first: 226307 microseconds;
second: 268437 microseconds

Comment: Would you like to explain what made you think the second one would be better? Without further analyzing it, the first version seems to insert directly into the inner map, where the second one you would first create a temporary one and move that back to the outer map?

Comment: If there is no obvious problem with your code and you just want a review or general tips, the question might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Questions here require a clear problem statement with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you enable optimizations for your timings? Both options perform the same for me.
As to "which code is better"... that is a very subjective question. If the performance is the same, it comes down to readability and maybe error handling (if you e.g. might run into memory issues or so). Personally, I find both options readable, with slight preference for the first one.

Comment: I think the first one need to search for the item and can not find one, then it inserts an empty pair.  The second inserts a pair if the hash is not conflict. @Ranoiaetep

Comment: *'The second inserts a pair if the hash is not conflict'* -- No, `emplace` will also search for the item, and the searching algorithm for `emplace` and `operator[]` should be identical.

Comment: Be careful, they are not equivalent if `ab_map`'s keys are not unique - if `std::to_string(i)` were not unique.

Comment: @Anna There is a difference in behaviour if an item already exists. In option 1), an existing item would be "updated" through the insertion. In option 2), if the item already exists, it will not be changed. Neither is better, it depends on which behaviour is desired.

Comment: What do the 'test1' and 'test2' mean? If tests are done on the same computer, the I'd say the variance of test results is much higher than difference between different methods. The correct way to measure the performance is to use a good benchmarking tool that would also print the standard deviation or something that describes tests accuracy.

Comment: Using my psychic powers, I think the OP failed to set optimization flags.

Comment: From quick-bench.com, [results](https://quick-bench.com/q/ySVY8WtIqFLRM14BE5WLuyh9ViY) are inverted (factor of 1.1).